# Docker File Location for Asp.Net core

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I am running Docker in Windows, using Linux containers.

I have an asp.net core hello-world app that writes a text file:

```
        var path = Path.Combine(
            Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "text.txt");

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, "text");
```

Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() comes back as "/app"

In my docker-compose I map /app to /usr/xxxxx

```
volumes:
  - /app:/usr/xxxxx
```

My question is: Where on my Windows file system is the /usr/xxxxx  ? I want to back it up so that it stays after containers are removed.

Comment: I blogged about this more with the solution @christian mentioned https://ianvink.wordpress.com/2020/07/29/docker-and-visual-studio-error-while-creating-mount-source-path/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volumes (actually [bind-mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)) use the format `host-path:container-path`.

It looks like you put it in the wrong order in the docker-compose file.
Also, as there is no folder called `/usr/xxx` on windows, just use a path that exists instead.

For example, you can create a directory called "backup" inside the directory with the docker-compose file, and then modify the docker-compose file like so

```yaml
volumes:
  -  "./backup:/app"
```

In the standard Dockerfile that Visual Studio generates, your application dll's are copied into `/app`. Therefore, it might be a bad choice to use `/app`. I'm actually not sure what happens if the bind-mount directory already exists with different data inside the container. But you could just write the file to another directory and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks - I have updated a blog about this so I don't forget https://ianvink.wordpress.com/2020/07/29/docker-and-visual-studio-error-while-creating-mount-source-path/